# How to add noise to a uiimage in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, textures

I'm trying to add noise to a uiimage - to display a texture effect. I'm not sure of the size of the image, so I don't want to create an image in photoshop.

Is there anyway to do this in monotouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check the below links

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html